# How to print a string from plist without "Optional"?

Tags: swift, plist

I load a value from a dictionary in a plist but when I print it to the console, it prints: Optional(Monday Title) rather than just "Monday Title".

How can I get rid of the Optional() of my value when printing?

```
var plistPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("days", ofType: "plist")
var plistArray = NSArray(contentsOfFile: plistPath!) as NSArray!

    for obj: AnyObject in plistArray {
        if var dicInfo = obj as? NSDictionary {
            let todayTitle: AnyObject? = dicInfo.valueForKey("Title")
            println(todayTitle)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try this pod https://github.com/T-Pham/NoOptionalInterpolation. It does exactly that.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

One way to get rid of the `Optional` is to use an exclamation point:

```
println(todayTitle!)
```

However, you should do it only if you are certain that the value is there. Another way is to unwrap and use a conditional, like this:

```
if let theTitle = todayTitle {
    println(theTitle)
}
```

Paste this program into [runswiftlang](http://www.runswiftlang.com/) for a demo:

```
let todayTitle : String? = "today"
println(todayTitle)
println(todayTitle!)
if let theTitle = todayTitle {
    println(theTitle)
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much for the quick answer. I'm still getting used to these optionals.

Comment: @vacawama Thanks for alerting me to it! It looks like runswiftlang stopped supporting online demos, so I copied re-typed the code and pasted it here with instructions on how to try int online. I also removed the question mark. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

With some try, I think this way is better.

```
(variableName ?? "default value")!
```

Use `??` for default value and then use `!` for unwrap optional variable.

Here is example,

```
var a:String? = nil
var b:String? = "Hello"

print("varA = \( (a ?? "variable A is nil.")! )")
print("varB = \( (b ?? "variable B is nil.")! )")
```

It will print

```
varA = variable A is nil.
varB = Hello
```

Answer (score 4):

Another, slightly more compact, way (clearly debatable, but it's at least a single liner)

`(result["ip"] ?? "unavailable").description`.

In theory `result["ip"] ?? "unavailable"` should have work too, but it doesn't, unless in 2.2

Of course, replace "unavailable" with whatever suits you: "nil", "not found" etc

Comment: Clever! As noted by @Jeremy, your default value should be of the same type as your optional. So, if you wanted to print an optional Int:
`var i:Int?; print("i is: \((i ?? 0).description)") // output: "i is 0"`

Answer (score 1):

## Swift 3.1

From Swift 3, you can use `String(describing:)` to print out optional value. But the syntax is quite suck and the result isn't easy to see in console log.

So that I create a extension of `Optional` to make a consistent `nil` value.

```
extension Optional {
    var logable: Any {
        switch self {
        case .none:
            return "⁉️" // Change you whatever you want
        case let .some(value):
            return value
        }
    }
}
```

How to use:

```
var a, b: Int?
a = nil
b = 1000
print("a: ", a.logable)
print("b: ", b.logable)
```

Result:

```
a: ⁉️
b: 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the proper process is for linking to other answers, but [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37843344/994104) applies here as well.

Valentin's answer works well enough for optionals of type `String?`, but won't work if you want to do something like:

```
let i? = 88
print("The value of i is: \(i ?? "nil")")  // Compiler error
```

Answer (score -1):

initialize

```
Var text: string? = nil
```

Printing

```
print("my string", text! as string)
```

This will avoid word "optional" before the string.