# Swift - what does Optional mean in log output?

Tags: ios, swift

When I get the value from a Text Field and cast it to an integer, I get log output that says `Optional(5)` if I inputted 5, or `Optional(1234)` if I inputted 1234.

What does `Optional()` mean?

Here is the code to get and cast the value:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myInput: UITextField!

// When a button is clicked, I log the value in the UI text field.
@IBAction func someButton(sender: AnyObject) {
  println(self.myInput.text.toInt())        
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25846561/swift-printing-optional-variable

Comment: It means it's an Optional. If you don't know what an Optional is, how can you use Swift at all? I mean, this is on the _first page_ of the Swift manual, for heaven's sake. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_496

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using Swift without even trying to learn Swift.

Comment: There are so many good close reasons for this question. http://stackoverflow.com/q/24003642/901059 It's also a duplicate.

Comment: Ok guys, bad question, downvoted to hell, I got it :) If I could close or delete it I would.  It was my first day doing Swift, and I didn't realize this was in the official docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Optional means the value is `Optional` type. It can be either `nil` or a value. When working with cocoa api most of the method parameters are optional type. To get actual value from optional value you either use `if-let` binding or force it to unwrap it with `!` operator. Suppose ve have a value of `a` optional type of `Int`. Let's define it first.

```
let a: Int? = 5
```

The `?` denotes it is an optional value. If you print this `a` it will write `Optional(5)`. Let's get the actual value from it.

```
if let actualA = a {
    println(actualA)
}
```

Now if `a` is not `nil` then the code inside if-let statement will be executed and it will print `5` on the console.

Optional types are for dealing with `nil` values in swift. They provide extra safety when working parameters and variables. If a value is not optional than it can never be `nil`. So we can safely do our work without worrying about `nil` values.