# php storing data in mysql as Optional(&quot;a&quot;) and not a normal String

Tags: php, mysql, json, swift

I have a problem in my swift app where whenever i register a new user in to login to my system, the string is parsed into something different and stores the username as  [see data entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAxVh.png) for example.

I have no clue as to why it is doing this. here is my code in xcode swift:

```
    let myURL = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8888/userRegister.php");
    let request =   NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myURL!);
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST";

    let postString = "email=\(userEmail)&password=\(userPassword)";

    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);


    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){

    data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
        print("error=\(error)")
        return
        }


        do{

        let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
            if let parseJSON = json{
             let resultValue = parseJSON["status"] as! String
                print("result:\(resultValue)")
                var isUserRegistered: Bool = false;

                if(resultValue == "success"){
                    isUserRegistered = true;
                }
                var messageToDisplay:String = parseJSON["message"] as! String;
                if (!isUserRegistered)
                {
                    messageToDisplay = parseJSON["message"] as! String;
                }

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: messageToDisplay, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
                    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default){ action in

                        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);
                    };

                    myAlert.addAction(okAction);
                    self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil);
            }


                )};


        } catch { print(error)}
    }




    task.resume();
```

my php files (userRegister.php)

```
<?php 

require("Conn.php");
require("MySQLDao.php");

$email = htmlentities($_POST["email"]);
$password = htmlentities($_POST["password"]);

$returnValue = array();

if(empty($email) || empty($password)) 
{
$returnValue["status"] = "error";
$returnValue["message"] = "Missing required field";
echo json_encode($returnValue);
return;
}

   $dao = new MySQLDao();
$dao->openConnection();
$userDetails = $dao->getUserDetails($email);

if(!empty($userDetails))
{
$returnValue["status"] = "error";
$returnValue["message"] = "User already exists";
echo json_encode($returnValue);
return;
}

$secure_password = md5($password); // I do this, so that user password cannot     be read even by me

    $result = $dao->registerUser($email,$secure_password);

 if($result)
  {
  $returnValue["status"] = "Success";
  $returnValue["message"] = "User is registered";
    echo json_encode($returnValue);
  return;
  }

$dao->closeConnection();

?>
```

and finally mysqlDao.php file where the queries are stored

```
<?php
class MySQLDao {
var $dbhost = null;
var $dbuser = null;
var $dbpass = null;
var $conn = null;
var $dbname = null;
var $result = null;

function __construct() {
$this->dbhost = Conn::$dbhost;
$this->dbuser = Conn::$dbuser;
$this->dbpass = Conn::$dbpass;
$this->dbname = Conn::$dbname;
}

public function openConnection() {
$this->conn = new mysqli($this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass, $this-    >dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
echo new Exception("Could not establish connection with database");
}

public function getConnection() {
return $this->conn;
}

public function closeConnection() {
if ($this->conn != null)
$this->conn->close();
}

public function getUserDetails($email)
{
$returnValue = array();
$sql = "select * from users where username='" . $email . "'";

$result = $this->conn->query($sql);
if ($result != null && (mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1)) {
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
if (!empty($row)) {
$returnValue = $row;
}
}
return $returnValue;
}

public function getUserDetailsWithPassword($email, $userPassword)
{
$returnValue = array();
$sql = "select id,username from users where username='" . $email . "' and      password='" .$userPassword . "'";

$result = $this->conn->query($sql);
if ($result != null && (mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1)) {
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
if (!empty($row)) {
$returnValue = $row;
}
}
return $returnValue;
}

public function registerUser($email, $password)
{
$sql = "insert into users set username=?, password=?";
$statement = $this->conn->prepare($sql);

if (!$statement)
throw new Exception($statement->error);

$statement->bind_param(ss, $email, $password);
$returnValue = $statement->execute();

return $returnValue;
}

}
?>
```

Thank you

Comment: Looks like your email and password fields are optional and you should unwrap them when you insert them into the string before posting

Comment: What does `$_POST["email"]` output as? Why entityize the email and password (passwords should be hashed)?

Comment: I dont see my fields being optional. can you point that out pbush25

Comment: Looks like you're posting `Optional("a")` as a value to PHP, so the error is most likely in your swift app. `htmlentities` in php replaces the `"` with `&quot;` and that's why you're getting `Optional(&quot;a&quot;)`. You might want to take a look at [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25846561/swift-printing-optional-variable) aswell?

Comment: @user3423164 I don't know where your email and password fields are declared, but because you're placing them into the string `"\(emailField) and some more text then \(passwordField)"` and those are the variables that are being placed incorrectly into your database, my first thought is that they might be optionals. There isn't enough code here for me to know for sure, that's why I just suggested it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working code before and after. Just unwrapped the optional variables.

Before:

```
let postString = "email=\(email)&password=\(password)&phone=\    (phone)&name=\(name)"
```

for example the name was stored like this: `Optional("Wissa")`.

After:

```
let postString = "email=\(email!)&password=\(password!)&phone=\    (phone!)&name=\(name!)"
```

This way it worked very well with me.