# swift3 How to remove Optional

Tags: swift, swift3, option-type, unwrap

this is my code:

```
 func uplouadPost() {

    // shortcut to data to be php

   let parseJSON = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "parseJSON") as? 
   NSDictionary
   let userID = parseJSON!["userID"] as! String
```

....

```
  if error == nil {

            do {

                // json containes $returnArray from php
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, 
  options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                print("========================\(userID)")
```

print I get ========================Optional(23)

But I don't want Optioanl

how to just get 23

What's more, I tried to unwrap the "userID" by this way. However it doesn't work

```
let unwrappedUserID = [userID]

print (unwrappedUserID)
```

Thank you guys

Comment: Your "unwrapping" code is incorrect.

Comment: Please refer this link for help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51356716/8334818

Answer (score 0):

The best method of checking for and unwrapping `Optionals` is using either a `guard` statement or `if-let` statements.

So suppose you have a dictionary defined as:

```
let parseJson: [String: Any]? = ["userId": 23]
```

Even though it has a value, it is still an `Optional` type so to access the values in the dictionary we want, we need to check for the possibility of it having a `nil` value, assuming we didn't create it and *know* that it has a real value.

Using `if-let` statements, we can do:

```
if let json = parseJson {
  // WILL ONLY EXECUTE IF parseJson IS NOT nil
  // json is now of type [String: Any] instead of [String: Any]?
  let userId = json["userId"]
  print("=========\(userId)") // =========23
}
```

This creates a new scope where the `json` constant now contains the non-nil and unwrapped optional value of `parseJson`. In that case if `parseJson` *did* equal `nil`, then the code inside of the `if-let` block would not execute.

The other option is a `guard` statement, which is very similar.

```
guard let json = parseJson else {
  // ONLY EXECUTES IF parseJson IS nil
  // MUST EXIT CURRENT SCOPE AS A RESULT
  return // or throw NSError()
}

let userId = json["userId"]
print("==========\(userId)") // ==========23
```

In this case, the code *after* the `guard` will only execute if `parseJson` is non-nil because the inside of the `guard` block *must* exit the scope.

Answer (score -2):

Try this, `let unwrappedUserID = userID!`

Comment: It is bad practice to implicitly unwrap optionals without having done `nil` value or error checking

Comment: true. I'm only showing OP the format of unwrapping optional.  `nil` and error checking is on his coding practice.