# Why is the word "Optional" being added when I print a string using a dictionary entry as the variable?

Tags: swift, dictionary

I am learning Swift and hacking around in a playground. I have the following Dictionary:

```
var person = [
    "first": "John",
    "last": "Smith",
    "age": 21
]
```

I am using the following line to print output:

```
"Your first name is \(person["first"]) and you are \(person["age"]) years old."
```

With this code, I get the following output:

```
// -> "Your first name is Optional(John) and you are Optional(21) years old."
```

I expected to receive the following as output:

```
// -> "Your first name is John and you are 21 years old."
```

Where is the Optional coming from? Why doesn't this simply print the value at the specified key? What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: You should really read the language guide, which covers Optionals, Dictionaries, and other language basics in great detail.

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov I have it downloaded, however I am currently reading this https://www.hackingwithswift.com/ for a quick breakdown of the language and the start the language guide.

Comment: This has been asked and answered repeatedly. Just search for `[swift] print optional`

Comment: @tymac I spent 30 minutes searching on SO for this plus read all of the suggested articles when I finished writing. I feel like I did my due diligence to search before asking.

Comment: I know so do I every time :)  lol  I feel your pain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Retrieving a value for a given key from a dictionary is always an optional because the key might not exist then the value is `nil`. Using String Interpolation `"\(...)"` the Optional is included as literal string.

To avoid the literal `Optional(...)` in String Interpolation you have to unwrap the optionals preferred in a safe way

```
if let first = person["first"] as? String, age = person["age"] as? Int {
   print("Your first name is \(first) and you are \(age) years old.")
}
```

Comment: The null coalescing operator `??` can also be handy here, to provide a default value in case the property is `nil`. e.g. `print("Your first name is \(person["first"] ?? "unknown") and you are \(person["age"] ?? "an unknown number of") years old.")`

Comment: Indeed, but in real life any person is supposed to have a first name and an age (I know that defeats the suggestion to use optional bindings) ;-)

Comment: @JesseAmano's solution also works, but only if `age` is saved as a `String`, if it remains as an `Int`, the `Optional` remains.

Comment: I definitely agree; I also think using `!` anywhere crashing the app wouldn't be desired behavior (so loading image assets and binding to storyboards might be exceptions) is a really bad idea, on par with `if expressionThatIsProbablyAlwaysTrue() { alwaysDoThis(); } else { presentAlert("lolz u'll never c this!!1!") }`. So I figured I'd add on that `??` is an alternative for anyone who thinks using `if` and `guard` to unwrap optional values is too verbose/bureaucratic (or some other gripe)

Answer (score 1):

Your string has not been unwrapped and is an optional that is why you see the word optional and the parenthesis. If you want them to go away you can put an ! to unwrap it. However, I would suggest handling it differently so you don't try to unwrap a nil value.

For example,

```
var person = [
"first": "John",
"last": "Smith",
"age": 21
]

print("Your first name is \(person["first"]) and you are \(person["age"]) years old.")
// prints: "Your first name is Optional(John) and you are Optional(21) years old."

print("Your first name is \(person["first"]!) and you are \(person["age"]!) years old.")
// prints: "Your first name is John and you are 21 years old."

let name = person["first"]!
let age = person["age"]!
print("Your first name is \(name) and you are \(age) years old.")
// prints: "Your first name is John and you are 21 years old."
```

Vadian has a great example of how to properly print this out as his example will not crash if you get something that is nil.

Comment: Would storing the value in a variable and then using said variable fix this?

Comment: No the variable would still need to be unwrapped

Answer (score -1):

Try to make it like this

```
"Your first name is \(person["first"]!) and you are \(person["age"]!) years old."
```

And then try to take a look at the perfect explanation here [Printing optional variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25846561/swift-printing-optional-variable)