# Difference between print(nil) and print(name) when var name: String? = nil

Tags: ios, swift

I'm a student who's new in Swift.

While I'm studying about the Optional, I got curious about the keyword nil, so I tried some experiment with it. I'm using Swift version 5.5.

As you can see in the image below, if I assign nil to a optional variable (which I named 'name') and then print it with print(name) and print("(name)") (string interpolation), I got nil on the console in both cases. (Line 5, 9)

But when I print nil without the optional variable, which I printed it with print(nil) and print("(nil)"), I got an error on both cases. (Line 7, 11)

[image]

I expected them all to print out nil but they didn't.
I really want to know the difference between those cases.

Comment: Please try to embed the image into the post instead of using a link :)

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25846561/printing-optional-variable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that `nil` isn't just one single value, like `null` in Java/C#.

`nil` is syntactic sugar for `Optional<Wrapped>.none`. There's one different kind of value for every possible `Wrapped`. E.g. there is `Optional<Int>.none` and `Optional<String>.none`, and you can't assign from one to the other, because they're unrelated types.

When you use `nil`, the value of the `Wrapped` generic parameter is inferred from context, much like when you do:

```swift
let a = Optional<Int>.none           // most explicit
let b: Optional<Int> = Optional.none // Generic Wrapped param inferred from the type annotation
let c: Optional<Int> = nil           // Same inference
```

`print` takes an `Any`, so that doesn't give any relevant contextual type information. When you say `print(nil)`, it's not clear what the typed of `Wrapped` should be. You might not care (because `Optional<Int>.none` and `Optional<String>.none` both print "nil"), but the type system can't leave it open ended, so it's a type error.

If you added contextual type information, it works, such as using a variable of a known type, or using a coercion:

```
print(nil as String?)
```

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question actually. If you look at the Swift documentation:

*Swift also introduces optional types, which handle the absence of a value. Optionals say either “there is a value, and it equals x” or “there isn’t a value at all”.*

So think of it as nil is the absence of some value. As an example if you have:

```
var name: String?
```

`name` can either be a string value, or the absence of a string value.

So it makes no sense to try and print nil explicitly since you already know that it's the absence of a value, however, it makes sense to print `name` to check if it has a string value and in that case what it is, or if it has no string value.

Comment: "The print function is telling you that you never just want to work with nil, and it makes no sense to print it explicitly, so the compiler prevents you from doing it." That's not why, and this isn't limited to just the `print` function. It'll happen in any other context where there's no contextual type information, like `let a = nil`. See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75324998/3141234

Comment: Agreed. The thinking here is reasonable, but it's simply incorrect. You can explore this by creating another function `func dothing(_ :Any) {}` and try to call it as `dothing(nil)`. You'll get the same error. The usefulness or lack of usefulness of printing doesn't matter here.

Comment: Hehe, kind of knew this was coming, because yes you are totally correct! I just thought it was a bit easier to explain it this way even though it’s of course not 100% what’s going on. I should probably have put a disclaimer about that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

The error message in XCode tells you exactly what happens: `nil is not compatible with expected argument type Any` - the `print` function expects a non-nil argument, as does the string interpolation with `\()`,

Comment: "the print function expects a non-nil argument" That's not quite true. It can handle `nil` fine, but to have a valid `nil` value, you need to know the specific type it should be. See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75324998/3141234

Comment: you are correct