# How to append optional string without adding optional?

Tags: ios, string, swift

here is what i do to parse int value:

```
anyObj = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as! Dictionary<String,AnyObject>

let categoryId = String(anyObj["id"])


let link = "categoryId" + categoryId

print(link)
```

where categoryId  is integer value

here is what i got :

```
/category/Optional(127)
```

How to remove the word optional ?

NOTE:
i have looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26347777/swift-how-to-remove-optional-string-character). also i have tried this also let link = "categoryId" + categoryId! but without luck

thanks

Comment: use String(format: "categoryId%@", (categoryId)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A value for a key of a dictionary is always optional because the key might not exist.

You need to unwrap the optional

```
let categoryId = String(anyObj["id"]!)
```

A safer solution is optional binding

```
if let categoryId = anyObj["id"] {
   let link = "categoryId" + String(categoryId)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var link = "categoryId";
if let categoryId = String(anyObj["id"]) {
    link += categoryId
}
```