# Swift How to remove optional String word

Tags: swift2

How do I remove Optional word

```
public func getCurrencySymbolFromCurrencyCode(currencyCode: String) -> String {
    // let currencyCode: String = "EUR"
    let locale: NSLocale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: currencyCode)
    let currencySymbol: String = "\(locale.displayNameForKey(NSLocaleCurrencySymbol, value: currencyCode))"
    print("Currency Symbol : \(currencySymbol)")

    return currencySymbol
}
```

Above code produces as follow:

```
Optional("$")
```

My question is why there is `Optional("$")` there, how can I remove the optional and just printing `$`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [swift How to remove optional String Character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26347777/swift-how-to-remove-optional-string-character)

Comment: check the below code its working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

//replace your code with  this your are not force unwrapping the symbol

```
      public func getCurrencySymbolFromCurrencyCode(currencyCode: String) -> String! {
          // let currencyCode: String = "EUR"
          let locale: NSLocale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: currencyCode)
          let symbol = locale.displayNameForKey(NSLocaleCurrencySymbol, value: currencyCode)!
          let currencySymbol: String = "\(symbol)"
          print("Currency Symbol : \(currencySymbol)")

          return currencySymbol
      }
```