# JSON's numeric value to string in swift?

Tags: json, swift, type-conversion

I get json from server and I need to convert id field to string in swift code.

The problem is json sometimes returns `"12345"`, sometimes returns `12345` (with or without quotes).

Is it possible to resolve this issue without of checking the value type and checking if the conversion result is `nil`?

**UPDATED**

Example of code I use with checking conversion result:

`let result = (some_index as? String) ?? String(some_index as! Int)`

The problem is in objective-C you have `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", some_object]`. But in swift you have optionals and it tries to insert word "optional" into result.

**UPDATED**

STOP spam with random answers about optionals. The question is concrete - "how to simply unwrap json value which may look like String, Int or doesn't exist at all?"

[swift How to remove optional String Character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26347777/swift-how-to-remove-optional-string-character)

In this question they ask how to convert `Int? -> Int`, `String? -> String` and similar. In my case I don't know if I have `Int?` or `String?` as the initial type.

Comment: Update your question with your current relevant code and clearly show what you need help with.

Comment: Why is that a problem to check the value type and check if the conversion has failed? If value is inconsistently a String or an Int, you have to check yourself, no other magical way.

Comment: Do you actually want to store a String or `Int` value? Moreover, as already requested by others, please provide more context.

Comment: Why does the server return quotation marks sometimes and the other times not. That's a very odd behaviour

Comment: @TPN1994, the problem appeared when project was rewritten into swift with its optionals

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov I would opt to use guards instead. If the conversion to int fails it will crash.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [swift How to remove optional String Character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26347777/swift-how-to-remove-optional-string-character)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `String`and `Int` conform to `CustomStringConvertible`, so you could optional downcast the value to `CustomStringConvertible` and use String Interpolation

```
let dict : [String:Any] = ["Foo" : 12345]

if let value = dict["Foo"] as? CustomStringConvertible {
    let result = "\(value)"
}
```

And blame the owner of the web service for sending inconsistent data ;-)

Comment: It seems to be ok to use this answer + method in category for `Optional`