# How do I check if a value is undefined in my Parse?

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I am making a simple app, and implementing the userInformation part. The user can edit his info, but I have trouble that if user doesn't put any info, it will crash when I try to retrieve data from an undefined column.

This is my code to retrieve the user data. If there is data to parse it won't crash, otherwise it will.

```
    let nickName = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("nickName") as! String
```

So I am asking how can I handle retrieving undefined value before crash?
            (please write full code for me)

Is there a way I can check value before I retrieve it?

```
///like this
if (value in parse  == "ABC") {
    print("yes")
}
```

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25779392/swift-optional-text-in-optional-value

Comment: You're telling it to crash if it can't unpack to a string - just stop doing that...

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. Why don't you check if `objectForKey` returns nil or not before unwrap the underlying value?

Answer (score 2):

if you want to retrieve objects (only defined objects) through query then u need to see

```
 query.whereKeyExists("nickName");
```

if u simply want to check retrieved coulmn's value is defined or not you can simply use

```
if(user["nickName"])
{
  // nickname exists for user ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, Try this code:

```
let query = PFUser.query()
    query!.whereKey("username", equalTo: "abcd")
    query!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
        (object, error) -> Void in
        if (object != nil) {
            if(object!.count != 0)
            {
                for messageObject in object! {
                    let photoUploaded : Bool = ((messageObject as! PFObject)["photoUploaded"] as? Bool)!
                    if (photoUploaded == true) {
                        if let userPicture = messageObject["profilePic"] as? PFFile {
                            userPicture.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                                if (error == nil) {
                                    let imageData = imageData
                                    let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                                    self.createrImage.image = image
                                } else {
                                    // Error handling
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            } // object is undefined here
        } // else is added here to get object is nill
    })
```

I am checking if the photo is uploaded with the user data. If is uploaded, I will get `true` as `Bool` value, if not uploaded, then `false` . If not defined, add else part and breakpoint at the comment to avoid crash. update me in case of any issue